# wp_list_pages by taxonomy?

Tags: wp-list-pages

I need help creating a Walker for wp_list_categories that filters through taxonomies and actually lists the pages at the end element.

I'm completely lost on how to go about this. I've successfully implemented a Walker for the wp_list_pages function but that obviously doesn't apply in this case because my wp_list_pages Walker relied on child-parent relationships

---

Additionally, I'd like to be able to specify which terms I want to return. Basically, I need a list filtered by taxonomy and terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
wp_list_categories()
```

Would be the way to go for taxonomies. Further functionality can be done either with a custom walker on this function (This seems to be the one resource: http://scribu.net/wordpress/extending-the-category-walker.html)

or write a custom SQL script.

In the end, I went with wp_list_pages and sorted by custom post type where:

```
post_type => 'custom-post-type'
```

is listed as an argument.